# How to tell if a motherboard is UMA or NUMA?

Tags: hardware

I want to build a very parallel (at least 24 cores) AMD opteron (bulldozer) system.

I'm looking at some motherboards and I can't figure out if they're UMA or NUMA (uniform memory access vs non-uniform memory access.)

Are most multi-socket motherboards one or the other architecture?

Here are two I was looking at:

Quad socket Tyan:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813151219

Dual socket Asus:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131643&Tpk=KGPR-D16

Comment: This is not off-topic according to the faqs... Does someone want to explain why this question is not appropriate here?

Comment: The way I understand it, questions about servers by professionals for professional use are the exact domain of this website.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, all AMD-headed stuff is NUMA. The "clue" you're asking for is checking the memory configuration - if some of the available memory banks are only usable if the second/third/forth CPU socket(s) are populated, you probably have a NUMA architecture.